# Pass filename variable into sed command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am attempting to write a small shell script that firstly defines a file name using date and then runs two sed commands which strip out certain characters.

My code is as follows:

```
filename=/var/local/file1/tsv_`date '+%d%m%y'`.txt
sed -i 's/\("[^,]*\)[,]\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/g' '&filename'
sed -i 's/\"//g' '&filename'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
sed: can't read &filename: No such file or directory
sed: can't read &filename: No such file or directory
```

Question is, how can I pass this filename variable into the sed command?

Thanks

Comment: please mark one of the answers to your post as an accepted answer so your post will show as resolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When doing shell scripting, for referencing variables the & (ampersand) is not used, but the $ (dollar sign):

```
filename=/var/local/file1/tsv_`date '+%d%m%y'`.txt
sed -i 's/\("[^,]*\)[,]\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/g' "$filename"
sed -i 's/\"//g' "$filename"
```

Also when referencing variables, double quotes must be used, if not, bash won't interpret the meaning of the $ sign.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use double-quotes when passing a variable to `sed`.  If you use single quotes, the variable will be read literally.

To use a shell variable in a command, preface it with a dollar sign ($). This tells the command interpreter that you want the variable's value, not its name, to be used.

```
filename=/var/local/file1/tsv_`date '+%d%m%y'`.txt
sed -i 's/\("[^,]*\)[,]\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/g' "$filename"
sed -i 's/\"//g' "$filename"
```